# Salvar dados JSON usando Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel-5

Ao salvar dados no banco *MySQL* com a coluna do tipo *JSON* utilizando o *Laravel*. Ele insere os dados dessa forma:

```
"{\"publish\":1,\"start_date\":\"2018-01-06\",\"start_time\":\"00:00\",\"end_date\":\"2018-01-09\",\"end_time\":\"00:00\"}"
```

Como faço para quando ele for inserido no banco ele fique dessa forma

`{"publish": 1, "end_date": "2018-01-13", "end_time": "00:00", "start_date": "2018-01-06", "start_time": "00:00"}`

Por que da primeira forma não estou conseguindo ler as informações no *template (blade)*.

Agradeço.

Comment: Qual.é o.codigo?

Comment: mostra como estas a retornar o json